# R:modificación de las etiquetas de las curvas de rarefracción

Tags: r

Usando este script:

```
    total.samples.rr <- sum(abun.hab.mat.rr)

    sample.rare.rr <- rarefy(abun.hab.mat.rr, total.samples.rr, se = TRUE, MARGIN = 1)

    par(mar = c(4.5, 4.5, 0.1, 1)) # bottom, left, top, right.

     rarecurve(abun.hab.mat.rr, step = 1, total.samples.rr, xlab = "Sample           Size", ylab = "Species", label = TRUE, col = c(1:10))
```

obtengo una gráfica así, dónde el tamaño de las etiquetas se solapan entre ellas y no dejan que se vean las lineas

[image: Rarefracción curva]

he probado a borrar las cajas de las etiquetas:

```
    rarecurve(abun.hab.mat, step = 1, total.samples, xlab = "Sample Size", ylab = "Species", label = TRUE, col = c(1:10), border=NA)
```

pero sigue solapandose entre ellas y a las curvas:

[image: curva de rarefraccion (2)]

¿Cómo puedo hacer las etiquetas o más pequeñas o transparentes para que no solapen a las lineas ni entre ellas? ¿o alguna otra solución?
Muchas gracias de antemano,
Un saludo.

Comment: Es posible extraer los datos que componen el gráfico? En caso afirmativo podrías graficarlos con ggplot y la legenda podrías generarla con ggrepe (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html)

Comment: Otra recomendación. Usualmente en tus preguntas usas "Rstudio" y esto no relevante de Rstudio (IDE) sino solamente a R (el lenguaje) por lo que no debieras mencionarlo ni si quierea en la pregunta. Con el tag [r] basta y sobra ;)

Comment: Para que el fondo sea transparente debes agregar `fill=NA` en la llamada a `rarecurve`. De cualquier manera no sé si va a ayudarte mucho,el gráfico es pequeño por lo que las etiquetas sin duda se van a superponer una sobre otra. La idea de jkbunst es buena, pero deberías pasar la lógica de `rarecurve` a `ggplot`, este enlaces tal vez te ayude en ese sentido: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234809/coloring-rarefaction-curve-lines-by-metadata-vegan-package-phyloseq-package

Comment: Muchas gracias jbkunst y Patricio por vuestra aportación y muchas gracias. En primer lugar tienes razón Patricio, fill =NA, junto con border=NA hace que cada etiqueta sea transparente. Por otro lugar, tomaré la consideración graficarlos en ggplot además de no usar más Rstudio para estas preguntas. Gracias de nuevo a los dos.